# Prevent md-switch toggle clicking line

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using md-switch to display a toggle inside of an Angular app. When I click the line it's on, anywhere, the switch toggles. But I've got the switch on a line with other controls so I only want it to toggle when the actual switch is clicked, not some content outside it. How do I instruct it to behave like this?

Snippet:

```
<md-list-item class="md-1-line" ng-repeat="rule in vm.rules | filter:{name:groupedRule.name}">
<div style="width: 40px;">{{rule.threshold}}</div>
<div flex>
    <md-slider min="10" max="40" ng-model="rule.threshold">
    </md-slider>
</div>
<div style="width: 40px;">
    <md-switch ng-model="rule.enabled"></md-switch>
</div>
```

**Update**
Here's a code pen demonstrating the issue: http://codepen.io/jsiegmund/pen/repwyR

**Update**
Issue #7937 on GitHub: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7937#issuecomment-207793522

Comment: By fixing the code. Where is it?

Comment: @JBNizet added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace `md-list-item` with a `div` - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/eZyRra?editors=1010#anon-login)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="SwitchDemoCtrl" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-list>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
      <div style="width: 40px;"> {{ data.threshold }} </div>
      <div flex>
        <md-slider min="10" max="30" step="1" ng-model="data.threshold">
        </md-slider>
      </div>
      <div layout-align="end center" flex-offset="5">
        <md-switch ng-model="data.cb1" aria-label="Switch 1">
          Switch 1: {{ data.cb1 }}
        </md-switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  </md-list>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jasper *I think* it's because md-list-item propogates the click event to the switch. I've created an example (http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/pypZRK?editors=1010) where clicking on the slider doesn't affect the switch, if that helps. If it does I can change my answer. I've found that sometimes not using some Angular Material directives gives one more control.

Answer (score 2):

As of current date, the correct solution to this issue is to add class like this:

`<md-list-item class="md-no-proxy">`

This will prevent the entire line of list item to be clickable.

[md-list-item documentation link](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdListItem#proxy-item)